# Facing problem in findView (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm new on Android Studio and I'm working on a project.
I'm facing this error

[image]

I've declared listview but don't know why it's not working.
 **CODE:**

```
package com.example.animation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class view_rooms extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    String mTitle[]={"Room1","Room2","Room3","Room4","Room5"};
    String mDescription[]={"Access Room1","Access Room2","Access Room3","Access Room4","Access Room5"};
    int images[]={R.drawable.lights_open,R.drawable.lights_open,R.drawable.lights_open,R.drawable.lights_open,R.drawable.lights_open};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_rooms);
        listView=findViewById(R.id.ListView);

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findViewById()` searches the view by id into the layout file. In this case into the layout: R.layout.activity_view_rooms. You need to define into this layout one ListView widget and assign one id to search with findViewById().

For example into the layout activity_view_rooms you need to include the view:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And later you can get the instance of view with finViewById() in this way:

```java
package com.example.animation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class view_rooms extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    String mTitle[]={"Room1","Room2","Room3","Room4","Room5"};
    String mDescription[]={"Access Room1","Access Room2","Access Room3","Access Room4","Access Room5"};
    int images[]={R.drawable.lights_open,R.drawable.lights_open,R.drawable.lights_open,R.drawable.lights_open,R.drawable.lights_open};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_rooms);
        listView=findViewById(R.id.list_view_id);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line `android:id="@+id/ListView"` in your `activity_view_rooms.xml`

So the code will looks like this:

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/ListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
```